# Convert a sub-make file to make file?

Tags: c#

I need to convert sub-make files into make-files, namely Windows C# sub-make files.

The sub-make files look like:

```
include Windows.def 

solution = someSolution.sln
```

Can I just save the sub-make file as ".make?" I apologize if I'm vague, but I've googled the subject and don't have much information.

Thanks

Comment: I learned that I can just re-name the files .make. 
Example: "file.submake" becomes "file.make"

Comment: I'm not sure that tagging this as C# is appropriate.  No C# code is involved here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about "nmake" makefiles?  I imagine you must first modify it to use [an exclamation point preceding the include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y32zxwh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) statement:

```
!include Windows.def
```

Comment: I appreciate that you're the only one to reply, but I believe the answer I was looking for varies from yours... :-/